# Whatsapp groups related

Tags: ios

i want to change my handset from iphone 4 to samsung galaxy grand2, though my phone number will be same. 
However, please do confirm as to whether i can retain in all existing groups after changing my phone

Nitin Tripathi

Answer (score 0):

## Yes, you can

The WhatsApp groups you previously belonged to will still be present and you should remain as a member of them so long as you keep the same number. However, any chat messages and media you've sent/received is not likely to be present.

As of now, there is [no official process](http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/general/28030001) by which you can transfer a WhatsApp backup from an iOS device to an Android device.

For reference you might want to take a look at [Google's Switch to Android](https://www.android.com/switch/) guide.